# Fixing weird jumping glitch in Jquery vertical accordion on wordpress theme

Tags: jquery, wordpress, accordion

I am totally new to JQuery and i've been building a wordpress site based off a template and there is this annoying glitch where the accordion menu jumps and sometimes just keeps jumping for a while after you roll off.
What i want to do is stop it from working as a hover and instead change it to only open/close on click.

This is the code i have

```
/*
```

Main Menu

*/

function mainMenu ()
{

```
jQuery("nav ul li").hover(function () 
{

    jQuery(this).find("ul").fadeIn(0).slideUp(0).slideDown(800);

}, function () 
{

    jQuery(this).find("ul").slideUp(800);       

});

jQuery("nav ul li").each(function () 
{

    if (jQuery(this).find("ul").size() > 0) jQuery(this).find("a").filter(":first").append(" +");

});
```

}

NOTE: This glitch only happens when you add a third level to the nav.
It's a common problem with this template, here is a video of the issue also
http://youtu.be/lgbxWbmzbaw

Answer (score 0):

Give the elements you are sliding a fixed width to prevent this problem. Without a fixed width, jQuery can't accurately calculate the target height.

Also, replace `.size()` with `.length`, `.size()` is depreciated and is a bad practice.

The only other way to prevent this issue without requiring a fixed width is to animate the height directly to a set height.

Comment: Ok, i do have a with set in my css, can you give me an example of what you mean? Thanks BTW

Comment: The ul element would need a set width, for example, `nav ul { width: 100px; }`

Comment: Interesting thing is, i do have that already and it's still bugging out. Check it out http://tinyurl.com/75nly26

Comment: Ah, you aren't getting a jumping problem, you are getting a bouncing problem. Your events are happening in odd places, and you aren't preventing the queue of multiple animations. More than likely it is due to the hover events of child ul's.

Comment: yea, i kinda figured this would stop if it was an action on click instead of hover. Suggestions to fix?

Comment: Do you need hover events on the child li's? it may be as simple as using `nav > ul > li` as the selector for `.hover` and adding `.stop(true,true)` before each animation.

Comment: i guess i don't need the hover